# Cannot list datagrid according to a condition

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

[SOLVED] - Had to change Id@ to @Id. Writing mistake.

I have this Application for registering GYM Members and their payments. On the MembersDataGridView, when you double-click on the row header, the PaymentsDataGridView opens with the payments list. Now I can list perfectly ALL payments, but I want to list only the specific member's payments. The Payments Id is equal to the Members Id.
So If a member's Id is 100, all his/her payments Id will be 100.

I'm using this code to call the payments from the database:

```
        public List<Payment> ListPayments(Payment entity)
        {
            List<Payment> Payments = new List<Payment>();

            string SELECT = "SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Id = Id@";

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SELECT, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = entity.Id;

                    var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        var payment = new Payment
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Id"]),
                            Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(sqlReader["Amount"]),
                            StartDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["StartDay"]),
                            EndDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EndDay"])
                        };

                        Payments.Add(payment);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Payments;
        }
```

And I'm using this on the PaymentsForm:

```
private void PaymentsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var payment = new Payment
    {
        Id = IdTextBox.Text.ToIntOrZero()
    };

    PaymentsDataGridView.DataSource = Connection.ListPayments(payment);
}
```

The PaymentsForm contains textboxes for the member's information. And the IdTextBox contains the member's Id, from where I get the Id to list all the payments. Now when I try to list the member's payments I get this exception at the `var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();` part:

> SQLException was unhandled.
>
> Invalid column name 'Id@'.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error: Change `Id@` to `@Id`
so that:

`string SELECT = "SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Id = @Id";`

Comment: Don't edit your question and write 'solved', you have to accept an answer to mark it solved.

Comment: I marked your answer as marked. I just had to wait 10mins before I did. Thanks again!